# Is it possible to insert data in different languages in table columns in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working in a Codeigniter application with language class.

So far, I have the application running perfect and translating all languages using language files.

But I need to add a new functionality related to translation.

**How this would work**:
When a user posts some data, it would be inserted on different columns being translated to different languages each column. That means database content (Data inserted using forms like description of post) being translated to various languages.

Because I can not create a language file for that so I need to do it this way for data being inserted.

I am looking for some suggestions. I can't figure out a way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the specifics of what you're trying to accomplish, but have you considered creating the language file programmatically? Rather than handwriting it, you could create it on the fly or after updating the database.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I need database content (Data inserted using forms like description of post) being translated to various languages.